# How to create a new string by combining values corresponding to keys in several dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, string

I have two dictionaries:

```
time = {'JAN':'A','FEB':'B','MAR':'C','APR':'D','MAY':'E','JUN':'F','JUL':'H'}

currency={'USD':'US','EUR':'EU','GBP':'GB','HUF':'HF'}
```

and a table consisting of one single column where bond names are contained:

```
bond_names=pd.DataFrame({'Names':['Bond.USD.JAN.21','Bond.USD.MAR.25','Bond.EUR.APR.22','Bond.HUF.JUN.21','Bond.HUF.JUL.23','Bond.GBP.JAN.21']})
```

[image]

I need to replace the name with a string of the following format: EUA21 where the first two letters are the corresponding value to the currency key in the dictionary, the next letter is the value corresponding to the month key and the last two digits are the year from the name.

I tried to split the name using the following code:

`bond_names['Names']=bond_names['Names'].apply(lambda x: x.split('.'))`

but I am not sure how to proceed from here to create the string as I need to search the dictionaries at the same time for the currency and month extract the values join them and add the year from the name onto it.

Comment: please see above added it as code thanks

Comment: Post your expected output as well please (not as an image)

Comment: Is the input `Bond.USD.FEB.21` supposed to become `BondUSB21` in the output? Or do you want the output to be `USB21`, `Bond.US.B.21`, or something else?

https:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you a list of what you need:

```
time = {'JAN':'A','FEB':'B','MAR':'C','APR':'D','MAY':'E','JUN':'F','JUL':'H'}

currency={'USD':'US','EUR':'EU','GBP':'GB','HUF':'HF'}

bond_names = {'Names':['Bond.USD.JAN.21','Bond.USD.MAR.25','Bond.EUR.APR.22','Bond.HUF.JUN.21','Bond.HUF.JUL.23','Bond.GBP.JAN.21']}

result = []

for names in bond_names['Names']:
    bond = names.split('.')
    result.append(currency[bond[1]] + time[bond[2]] + bond[3])

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this:

```
import pandas as pd

time = {'JAN':'A','FEB':'B','MAR':'C','APR':'D','MAY':'E','JUN':'F','JUL':'H'}
currency = {'USD':'US','EUR':'EU','GBP':'GB','HUF':'HF'}
bond_names = pd.DataFrame({'Names': ['Bond.USD.JAN.21', 'Bond.USD.MAR.25', 'Bond.EUR.APR.22', 'Bond.HUF.JUN.21', 'Bond.HUF.JUL.23', 'Bond.GBP.JAN.21']})
bond_names['Names2'] = bond_names['Names'].apply(lambda x: currency[x[5:8]] + time[x[9:12]] + x[-2:])
print(bond_names['Names2'])
# 0    USA21
# 1    USC25
# 2    EUD22
# 3    HFF21
# 4    HFH23
# 5    GBA21
# Name: Names2, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

With extended regex substitution:

```
In [42]: bond_names['Names'].str.replace(r'^[^.]+\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.(\d+)', lambda m: '{}{}{}'.format(curre
    ...: ncy.get(m.group(1), m.group(1)), time.get(m.group(2), m.group(2)), m.group(3)))                    
Out[42]: 
0    USA21
1    USC25
2    EUD22
3    HFF21
4    HFH23
5    GBA21
Name: Names, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```py
import pandas as pd

time = {'JAN':'A','FEB':'B','MAR':'C','APR':'D','MAY':'E','JUN':'F','JUL':'H'}
currency={'USD':'US','EUR':'EU','GBP':'GB','HUF':'HF'}

bond_names=pd.DataFrame({'Names':['Bond.USD.JAN.21','Bond.USD.MAR.25','Bond.EUR.APR.22','Bond.HUF.JUN.21','Bond.HUF.JUL.23','Bond.GBP.JAN.21']})

bond_names['Names']=bond_names['Names'].apply(lambda x: x.split('.'))

for idx, bond in enumerate(bond_names['Names']):
    currencyID = currency.get(bond[1])
    monthID = time.get(bond[2])
    yearID = bond[3]
    bond_names['Names'][idx] = currencyID + monthID + yearID
```

Output

```
   Names 
0  USA21 
1  USC25  
2  EUD22 
3  HFF21  
4  HFH23  
5  GBA21
```